# Adding multiple elements in a list to list.count (Python)

Tags: list, python-2.7

Apologies for the somewhat vague title, I'll try explain more here.

Currently, I have the following code, which counts the number of times the values "y" and "n" show up in the list called "results".

```
NumberOfA = results.count("y")
NumberOfB = results.count("n")
```

Is there a way of making it so that, for example, values such as "yes" are also counted towards NumberOfA? I was thinking something along the lines of the following:

```
NumberOfA = results.count("y" and "yes" and "Yes")
NumberOfB = results.count("n" and "no" and "No")
```

But that doesn't work. This is probably a pretty easy one to solve, but hey. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As for why your answer above does not work, it is because Python will just take the final value of the expression you pass in:

```
>>> 'Yes' and 'y' and 'yes'
'yes'
```

Therefore your `count` will be off because it is just looking for that final value:

```
>>> results.count('yes' and 'y')
1
>>> results.count('yes' and '???')
0
```

Would something like this work? Note that this depends on their being only yes/no-esque answers in the list (will be wrong if things like 'Yeah....um no' are in there):

```
In [1]: results = ['yes', 'y', 'Yes', 'no', 'NO', 'n']

In [2]: yes = sum(1 for x in results if x.lower().startswith('y'))

In [3]: no = sum(1 for x in results if x.lower().startswith('n'))

In [4]: print yes, no
3 3
```

The general idea is to take your results list and then iterate through each item, lowercasing it and then taking the first letter (`startswith`) - if the letter is a `y`, we know it is a `yes`; otherwise, it will be `no`.

You can also combine the steps above if you want by doing something like this (note this requires Python 2.7):

```
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> results = ['yes', 'y', 'Yes', 'no', 'NO', 'n']
>>> Counter((x.lower()[0] for x in results))
Counter({'y': 3, 'n': 3})
```

`Counter` objects can be treated just like dictionaries, so you would now essentially have a dictionary that contained the counts of `yes`'s and `no`'s.

Comment: I'm just getting a kind of template down here; eventually it'll take any and all questions, along with choice of answers, not just "Yes" and "No". This is a really nice way of solving my current problem, though. I like it!

Comment: @dantdj Ah gotcha - well in any case, glad it helped! The `Counter` feature can be super useful in a lot of cases, so definitely something worth exploring if possible. Good luck with everything!

Answer (score 1):

```
NumberOfA = results.count("y") + results.count("yes") + results.count("Yes")
NumberOfB = results.count("n") + results.count("no") + results.count("No")
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a method

```
def multiCount(lstToCount, lstToLookFor):
    total = 0
    for toLookFor in lstToLookFor:
        total = total + lstToCount.count(toLookFor)
    return total
```

Then

```
NumberOfA = multiCount(results, ["y", "yes", "Yes"])
NumberOfB = multiCount(results, ["n", "no", "No"])
```